# No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available into the primary datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to configure Spring Boot to use 2 datasources using JNDI:

application.properties:

```
spring.production.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_gateway
spring.production.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.production.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.production.datasource.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.production.datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

spring.warehouse.datasource.jndi-name=java:/global/production_warehouse
spring.warehouse.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.warehouse.datasource.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDBDialect
spring.warehouse.datasource.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.warehouse.datasource.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Primary datasource:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "org.datalis.plugin.production.entity", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "productionEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "productionTransactionManager"
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ContextProductionDatasource {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionDataSourceProperties")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production.datasource")
    public JndiPropertyHolder productionDataSourceProperties() {
        return new JndiPropertyHolder();
    }   

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.production.datasource")
    public DataSource productionDataSource() {        
        JndiDataSourceLookup dataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        DataSource dataSource = dataSourceLookup.getDataSource(productionDataSourceProperties().getJndiName());
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionEntityManager") 
    public EntityManager productionEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Primary
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "production")
    @Bean(name = "productionLocalEntityManager")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean mySqlEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
         return  builder.dataSource(productionDataSource()).persistenceUnit("production").packages("org.datalis.plugin.production.entity").build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionTransactionManager")    
    public PlatformTransactionManager productionTransactionManager(final EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "productionExceptionTranslation")
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor productionExceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private static class JndiPropertyHolder {
        private String jndiName;

        public String getJndiName() {
            return jndiName;
        }

        public void setJndiName(String jndiName) {
            this.jndiName = jndiName;
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use the entity manager this way:

```
@Service
@Transactional(value = "productionEntityManager")
public class ..... {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "production")
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

But I get an error during deployment:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Do you know where my configuration is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a bean for `EntityManagerFactory`. You're requesting it here:

```
public EntityManager productionEntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
```

Try adding

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "productionEntityManagerFactory") 
public EntityManagerFactory productionEntityManagerFactory() {
    return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("production");
}
```

Comment: Now I get `Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named production`